# How to make left join and group by in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to join 3 tables 2 of them inner join one of them left join after that i want to make group by. However, it gives an error. How can I handle that ?

this is code :

```
var people = from u in db.User.ToList()
                                 join o in db.Offer.ToList() on u.UserId equals o.UserID where o.Statu == "Accepted"
                                 join oz in db.log.ToList() on new { x1 = u.UserId.ToString(), x2 = o.CampaignId.ToString() } equals new { x1 = oz.ID, x2 = oz.CampaignID } into ps
                                 from tbl in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 group new { u, o, tbl } by new { u.UserId, o.CampaignId, o.Target, tbl.ID} into grp
                                 select new { Username = grp.Key.UserId, CampaignID= grp.Key.CampaignId, Target = grp.Key.Target, id = grp.Key.ID};
```

Error occurs when i use tbl in group by. But i need to use it. I think some values comes null so it gives an error. How can i handle this ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @canton7 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: try `group new { ... } by new { ... ID: tbl?.ID }`.  'Tbl' can be null so you want to account for that.

Comment: Why are you doing `ToList` on the tables - that will cause all the data in the three tables to be pulled over to your client before doing the `join`. You should put off doing the `ToList` (and probably do `AsEnumerable()`) as late as possible.

Comment: Thank you @NetMage